# ¿Como matar(kill) procesos que exceden tope de memoria?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, linux-mint

¿alquien que me ayude para poder matar automaticamente procesos que exceden en memoria?

Comment: Por favor, lee [ask]. Pese a que es una pregunta autorrespondida, formula la pregunta de tal manera que la misma esté adaptada al formato del sitio. Recuerda que [es.so] no es un blog.

Comment: Suena como el tipo de cosas para las que se usan los `cgroups` .

Comment: Hola, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, No has dado una explicación exacta de tu situación o problema, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigos de Linux:

Como ya saben Chrome y Firefox son unos devoradores y ladrones de memoria jjj; Vscode no ayuda tampoco y por si fuera poco crea un proceso con la extencion TabNine que a veces se sale de control sobrepasando los 700Mb e incluso 1Gb.

Pues dada la problematica les traigo la solucion, para que ayude a otros ya que yo no la encontre en internet.

Un Script para monitorear una aplicacion y matar el proceso que mas consume memoria. Lo bueno es que no mata toda la aplicacion, solo el proceso que excede el tope que ustedes le coloquen:

primer script kill_mem.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

numPro=$(ps aux | awk '{print $6,$2,$11}' | sort -nr|grep $1|head -1|awk '{print $2}')

while [ numPro=1 ];
do
numPro=$(ps aux | awk '{print $6,$2,$11}' | sort -nr|grep $1|head -1|awk '{print $2}')
SIZE=$(ps aux | awk '{print $2,$11,$6}' | sort -nr|grep $numPro|head -1|awk '{print $3/1024 " MB\t\t"}')
SIZEMB=${SIZE%.*}

echo "Process id ="$numPro" Size = "$SIZEMB" MB"
if [ $SIZEMB -gt $2 ];
then 
echo "Tamaño se ha excedido.\nKilling the process......"
`kill -9 $numPro`
echo "Killed the process"
sleep 10
else
sleep 1
echo "Tamaño no se ha excedido"
fi

sleep 9
done
```

segundo script para colocarlo en aplicaciones de inicio:

```
#!/bin/sh

cd ~/bin/scripts/

sh kill_mem.sh chrome 640 & sh kill_mem.sh TabNine 640
```

Pues ya saben como es lo pegan en un archivo .sh(lo recomendado es en ~/bin/ si no existe creen la carpeta bin en su /home/suusuario/bin) y le dan permisos de ejecucion. Los topes de memoria esta en Mb, les recomiendo que les pongan un tope algo mas elevedo de lo que deseean, por ejemplo mi tope es de 500Mb yo le coloque 640 porque la salida del comando ps muestra un consumo un poco mas elevado que el monitor del sistema. Pero estan en la libertad de probar y ajustarlo a su gusto y necesidad.

El script esta diseñado para actuar como un demonio-policia en su sistema es decir siempre estara ejecutandose y verificando por lo que recomiendo que comenten con un # las lineas donde se imprime texto, ya saben de esta forma:

```
#echo "Killed the process"
```

: para evitar cualquier consumo en la ram.

Pues amigos eso es todo, el que quiera mejorarlo esta en la libertad y porfa comparta para ayudar a otros que tambien lo necesitan.

Dios les bendiga.

Edicion: Para mas detalles consultar en este foro: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=2278986#p2278986

Comment: @Benito-b Esa edición no mejora en nada la respuesta, es supérflua y le mete bronca a la cosa más inocente del mundo.

Comment: @Alfabravo Yo no creo que la política ni la religión tengan cabida en StackOverflow (ni en ningún otro entorno profesional, en su vida privada cada cual es libre de adorar al ente que prefiera).

Comment: @Benito-B estás usando tu propia creencia para moderar. Llévalo al chat o a meta y con gusto revisamos entre todos.